# Cpanel Logs - seconds per request

Tags: php, cpanel

i have a PHP app that makes various requests per hour. However, there is a request that causes slowness, and i don't know what request causes this.

cpanel logs, shows logs like this:

````
192.xx.xx.xx - - [12/Jan/2020:12:04:57 +0000] "POST /configuracoes/gettecnologiasforactivities HTTP/1.0" 200 173 "https://url.com/contratos/novocontrato" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36"
193.xx.xx.xx - - [12/Jan/2020:12:04:59 +0000] "POST /configuracoes/gettarifarioforactivities HTTP/1.0" 200 587816 "https://url.com/contratos/novocontrato" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36" ```
````

I want something like this, but to tell me how many seconds it took to process each request.

One solution, would be to go to each route in my PHP app, and put a datetime at the beginning of the route and other datetime at the end of the route, but i have many routes.

does cpanel do this?
what alternatives are there?